# How to execute a procedure having cursor in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, cursor

I know how to execute a stored procedure in SQL Server2008 but I'm clueless in executing a stored procedure containing a cursor in it.

My code:

```
 BEGIN TRANSACTION 
 GO

DROP PROCEDURE SampleProcedure
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SampleProcedure 
AS 
    DECLARE @FirstName varchar(64)

    DECLARE c1 CURSOR READ_ONLY
    FOR
        SELECT FIRST_NAME
        FROM EMPLOYEE

    OPEN c1

    FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @FirstName

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT @FirstName

        FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @FirstName
    END

    CLOSE c1
    DEALLOCATE c1

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I have seen executing a procedure with cursor in Oracle but couldn't find in SQL Server. Please tell me how to execute the stored procedure which contains cursor.

---Thanks

Comment: There's no difference in how to execute a stored procedure - whether it contains a cursor or not .... - just `EXEC SampleProcedure`, or use `EXEC sp_executesql` if you prefer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing the SP.

```
EXEC SampleProcedure
```

Comment: Thanks balaji for your reply. As you and @marc_s suggested  the command "EXEC SampleProcedure" is working , but i didn't get the expected output. I expected all the FirstNames of EMPLOYEE but I got the output "Command(s) completed successfully". Can you tell me where am i doing wrong?